# Conditional rendering react-redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-table

i have some problem i can't figure out.
i have some component inside i'm using react-table plugin.

on `componentDidMount` method i have to call redux action which get data from api and then i'm passing this data to react-table.

here is my **componentDidMount** method where i call to **redux** action.

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getData() 
}
```

here is my action:

```
export const FETCH_DATA_START = 'FETCH_DATA_START'
export const FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS = 'FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS'
export const FETCH_DATA_FAILED = 'FETCH_DATA_FAILED'

export const getOffBoardingData = () => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch({
            type: FETCH_DATA_START
        })
        fetch(baseUrl, {
                credentials: "include",
                method: "GET",
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then((res) => {
                dispatch({
                    type: FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS,
                    payload: res.result
                })
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                dispatch({
                    type: FETCH_DATA_FAILED,
                    payload: 'error'
                })
            })
    }
}
```

and here is my reducer.

```
import { FETCH_DATA_START, FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS, FETCH_DATA_FAILED } from 'store/actions/getData'

let initialState = [{
    items: null
}]

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case FETCH_DATA_START:
            return {...state}
        case FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS:
            return { ...state, items: action.payload} 
        case FETCH_DATA_FAILED: 
             return {...state}
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

everything work well here i think.

here is in my component i'm trying to make conditional rendering like:

```
 if (this.props.getDataReducer.items != null) {
        return (<div>
            <p>Loading...</p>
        </div>);
      } else { 
     return(
          <ReactTable className="-striped -highlight"
              data={this.props.getDataReducer.items}
              columns={columns} 
                                 />
       )
}
```

here is i make conditional rendering for my data. If items is null return some loading text else return react-table with data which came from api.

but i don't know how react-table trying to rendering when data null too.

where i return react-table i'm trying to make console.log my data but it's return undefined

sometimes component rendering without problem sometimes just giving error that data is undefined.

I make mistake about conditional rendering?

i tried to make that: component will wait to data and only when data will come that time component will be rendering.

where i make mistake?

Comment: try `if (this.props.getDataReducer.items) { //react table   } else { // loading  }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem you're having is setting your condition to specifically check for a null value. You should check if items is simply a **truthy** value. Since React-Table's data property accepts an array, you should also check that items has a length as well.

1) Update the condition in your component

```
 if (this.props.getDataReducer.items && this.props.getDataReducer.items.length >= 0) {
        return (<div>
            <p>Loading...</p>
        </div>);
      } else { 
     return(
          <ReactTable className="-striped -highlight"
              data={this.props.getDataReducer.items}
              columns={columns} 
                                 />
       )
}
```

2) Not sure if this is a typo, but the initial-state in your reducer looks messed up.

```
let initialState = [{
    items: null
}]
```

Your reducer is returning a new state object. if you were to spread the initial-state into it, you would get some unintended additional properties that wouldn't be useful to you. I believe you're looking for:

```
let initialState = {
    items: null
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Your initial state is an array but I guess you wanted an object.

```
let initialState = [{
    items: null
}]
```

what you want is

```
let initialState = {
    items: null
}
```

To put it in words, in the first case `getDataReducer` returns an array with `{items: null}` in the first position,
so to get `items` you need to `getDataReducer[0].items`.
But if you change it to an object you can simply, `getDataReducer.items`.

2. And more importantly, your check logic is inverted.

```
 if (this.props.getDataReducer.items != null) {
   // ...loading component
 }
```

should be

```
 if (this.props.getDataReducer.items === null) {
    // ...loading component
 }
```

3. Consider refactoring, and adding a `isLoading` variable in your state,
   which you should set to `true` in the `FETCH_DATA_START` and to `false` in the `SUCCESS` and `FAILURE` cases.
   Checking if the `items` are `null` won't necessarily mean that they are loading, as your app and code grows it is better to be more specific about what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the condition simpler to handle for undefined and null:

```
 if (this.props.getDataReducer.items) {
        return (<div>
            <p>Loading...</p>
        </div>);
      } else { ... 
 }
```

One more good practise for code clarity, it's best to have custom functions handle these conditions, so that *render()* has only one *return*.